# Trying to display first two numerical numbers

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract

I am trying to parse this so the numbers before "-" are displayed only. Sometimes it will be a single digit and sometimes double.

I tried
=LEFT(B4,FIND("-",B4)-1)

And it shoots an error. [image: image of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B4); "(\d+)")*1
```

for array:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B4:B); "(\d+)")*1))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C1:C), "^(\d+)")*1))
```

[image]

Comment: The first one says it doesn't match text of the function. The second one doesn't shoot an error is just a blank cell

Comment: @TooTallDerr can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yes https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F68Qcnw6UvopBcK1JAQKQ_sgRF8RsOIoJY-6JXx2zNM/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @TooTallDerr answer updated

Comment: What would I change to get the numbers after the "-"?

Comment: @TooTallDerr see E1 and H1 in your shared sheet